# 3rd party systems not supporting XA protocol

Tags: architecture, transactions, distributed

How can I implement distributed transactions involving 3rd party systems/API's which do not support XA protocol ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two cases:

- you don't have the source code of the 3rd party system, you can't
- you have the source code

  - it already uses transactions, you need to implement the XA spec on top
    of their transaction semantics. This requires an XA specialist
  - forget about it. You would need to introduce transaction semantics to
    the product.